# Foursquare Location Hash Store as a Rails Model Attribute / Column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, serialization, hash, foursquare

I'm calling the Foursquare API using the Foursquare2 Ruby wrapper https://github.com/mattmueller/foursquare2

If I initialize the client in Rails Console with:

```
client = Foursquare2::Client.new(:client_id =>'CLIENT_ID', :client_secret => 'CLIENT_SECRET')
```

then I make a call to the Foursquare API by the location_id (using 5104 for example).

```
restaurant = client.venue(5104)
```

this returns a giant Ruby Hashie::Mash. So if I only want the location Hash then I do

```
restaurant.location
```

which gives me this "location hash"

```
#<Hashie::Mash address="4 Clinton St." cc="US" city="New York" country="United States" crossStreet="at E Houston St." lat=40.721294 lng=-73.983994 postalCode="10002" state="NY">
```

now if I do `restaurant.location.address`
this returns `=> "4 Clinton St."`

So now, exiting Rails Console and entering a Rails App. My question - As an after_save method call in my Rails "Restaurant" Model, I am saving this "location hash" in my model in the "foursquare_location" column as a :text field.

In my "Restaurant" view template to show the Restaurant address details, how can I write my template so that I can call @restaurant.foursquare_location.address so that it accesses the address key to return the address value?

I'm not sure if I can just directly save the Foursquare API response directly to my SQLite3 Database in a :text column and have it maintain its hash structure.

I really appreciate the help here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the ActiveRecord `serialize` method:

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :foursquare_location
end
```

You can then assign an object to be the value of `foursquare_location`.

This should work with `Hashie::Mash` (I've never tried it myself, but it works fine with regular hashes). You might get a slight performance hit if you're accessing a lot of records at once, and it's a bit more difficult to query this field, but it should work for what you've described.

Comment: I can see that this is working to serialize the Hashie::Mash into a nicely formatted hash when I show the record using <%= Model.foursquare_location %> but how do I display in my view just one value based on a key such as :address?

Comment: Hi @ZachKemp This solution helped me to serialize the Hash but still unsure how to access each key:value in the hash from my View.  Can you please help? Thank you.

Comment: You should be able to access it with `@restaurant.foursquare_location.address`. The serialized object will be automatically loaded when the restaurant is retrieved from the database.

Comment: When I'm doing <%= @restaurant.foursquare_location.address %> from my rails app, it gives me this error "undefined method `address' for #<String:0x000000056d1988>".  What you described did work for me when doing it in Rails console. I wonder if the database is storing the Hash as a string formatted as a hash?

Comment: Ah okay, I was testing this with a record that was saved before the serialize method was applied to the :foursquare_location attribute. So I guess it was being saved as a string.  Creating a new record after applying serialize to the attribute does store the record as a Hash instead of a string. So I can indeed do something like @restaurant.foursquare_location.address now. Thanks for your answr!

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't fully tested this exact approach out with the Hashie, you could probably do this using the ActiveRecord::Store. This provides a wrapper around storing a hash out in one column in the database.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html

This is a cut down example from a rails application I'm working on. The model has a column called days_hours which I can then reference as if they were actual attributes.

```
class ProposedEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
  store :days_hours, accessors: [:mon, :tue, :wed, :thu, :fri, :sat, :sun]
end
```

In IRB:

```
my_event = ProposedEvent.new
my_event.days_hours = {:mon => '7, 8', :tue => '14, 15'}
```

This then gets stored down in the database for you and you can just use the convenience methods for accessing this, just as if you had these stored as separate columns.

```
puts my_event.mon
=> "7, 8"
```

Hope that works for your scenario.

Comment: Just one note, this method will only be available to you if you're using I believe Rails 3.2. It might have been around a little earlier than that, but I know it's a fairly recent addition.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I didn't give this a try because the serialize method in ActiveRecord seemed like a more direct answer to the question.